# Deploy c# project having ms-access database

Tags: c#, ms-access, deployment

How to deploy (create .exe/setup file) a C# project having database in ms-access??

Below is the connection string which I used in my project.

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + @"Data source= C:\Users\ViPuL\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\feedback@MERI\feedback@MERI\bin\feedback.mdb";
```

Comment: Depends on your deployment method, and since everywhere is different it's hard to say. I can guarantee that you're going to have to generate the path for the access database in code. That hardcoded location isn't going to work on anyone else's computer besides yours.

Comment: @Cameron that exactly what I am asking, the application should run on remote systems. What changes should I make in order to do the same....

Comment: Your question makes it seem as if you're asking how to deploy your application rather than how to make your application work in it's deployed location.

Comment: Look at the [OleDbConnectionStringBuilder documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx). I would use that for creating the connection string. As for where the database file is actually stored, that's up to you and your company's policies. I'd personally store it in AppData, and by using `Environment.GetSpecialFolder(SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)`. Best of luck.